# What's the correct way of going back to first temperature after thermal expansion

Tags: thermodynamics

It's common to state the linear thermal expansion equation as:

$\Delta L = L \times \alpha_L \times \Delta T $

If you increase a temperature and then decrease back to the starting point, this equation implies:

$ \Delta L_1 = L_0 \times \alpha_L \times \Delta T $

$ \Delta L_0 = (L_0 + \Delta L_1) \times \alpha_L \times -\Delta T =
 (L_0 \times \alpha_L \times -\Delta T) + (L_0 \times \alpha_L^2 \times -\Delta T^2) = -\Delta L_1 - L_0 \times (\alpha_L\times\Delta T)^2$

However, $\Delta L_0 + \Delta L_1$ should zero out (return to previous lenght). What's happening here exactly? Is the error caused by an unmodeled change in $\alpha$? Should I divide by $\alpha$ when going back or would this be an error?

Comment: The use of coefficient of linear expansion is only an approximation.  What you are asking about is a second order effect (multiply two very small quantities together ($\Delta L \Delta T$)) and so given the approximate nature of the predicted expansions being slight wrong is not really significant. To reduce the error both ways with the coefficient depending on temperature one should do an integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strictly correct definition of the coefficient of linear expansion is in terms of differentials:  $dL=L\alpha dT$.  If you use this equation, you will recover the original length exactly.  The equation $\Delta L = L\alpha \Delta T$ is only an approximation.